# Why tables and stored procedures not stored after restore database?

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have a database in SQL Server that i create backup file from it. Now i create a new database and i try to restore backup to this new database.

I try to restore a database from a `.bak` file. When I restore it in SQL Server, I get a "successful" message, but all tables and stored procedures are not restored.

What is problem?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing tables & stored procedures to see if they show up? Have you tried a new query and running a select statement against one of the tables that was restored?

Comment: ok I refresh tables and stored procedures but dont solved. Then i execute query that get error : Invalid object name

Comment: These are older threads, but they may help out for your situation: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711474/invalid-object-name-after-restoring-sql-server-2008-database

Comment: Not relevant to my case

Comment: My first guess is that you didn't restore to the database you thought you restored to, or the backup doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Backup file contains all data because when i restore this file into database with same name restored currently!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this settings and restored currently.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> but all tables and stored procedures are not restored.

It means that you can see newly restored database in SQL server. in that case verify the `.bak` file to check whether it's got actually all those required Tables/Procedures part of it, or the same `.bak` file might have appended with empty database backup (for some reason). You can check that with following query:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Backups\AppendedBackup.bak';
```